# How can I define and refer to custom user groups in Django that I can sort against like user.is_superuser?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I’ver created some custom user groups in my Django app because I want to show them different admin fieldsets.
I thought they would work similarly to `user.is_superuser`.

But they don’t.

I have this def in my ModelAdmin:

```
def is_approver(user):
        return user.groups.filter(name='approver').exists()
```

(I don’t know what that’s called, by the way. Do you just call it a “def”?)

So this works:

```
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return self.superuser_fieldset
```

I get the expected fieldset.

But this doesn’t work:

```
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_approver:
            return self.approver_fieldset
```

However, this does work:

```
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name='approvers').exists():
         return self.approvers_fieldset
```

So, I guess my basic question is: why don’t my `def`s work like I expect?

(Python 3.9.7, Django 3.1)

Comment: def is the keyword for defining a function. If its within a class it would be a method. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: Thank you @kni9ht. In that case this is (or is intended to be) a method.

Answer (score 1):

add this code in the user model

```
@property
def is_approver(self):
    return self.groups.filter(name='approver').exists()
```